# sprintf does not fill the buffer correctly

Tags: c, linux, file, printf

I am using `write` to create a csv file with the following type of values on every line

```
int16_t, int16_t, int16_t, int64_t, uint64_t
```

First a buffer is filled using sprintf and the it is passed to write. However, there is only one line with all the values in the written file. No new line.

```
static char line[34];



sprintf(line, "%d,%d,%d,%ld,%lu\n", ...);

write(fd_csv_data, line, sizeof(line));
```

%d,%d,%d,%ld,%lu makes 32 bytes in total, adding \n and \0 results in 34. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Depending on the values, it could overflow `line`. Use `snprintf` instrad. Check whether the buffer is actually sufficient. Also you probably want to pass the `strlen(line)` to write, not `sizeof(line)` (e.g. `line` may have fewer bytes than `sizeof(line)` and you don't want to print null or uninitialised bytes).

Comment: "%d,%d,%d,%ld,%lu makes 32 bytes in total,". How did you reach that conclusion? Show us the `...` and the rest of the code as a [minima verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can verify ourselves.

Comment: Very dangerous code.... `line` should be much bigger (like `char line[256];`) and `write` should be called using `strlen(line)` - not `sizeof(line)`

Comment: int16_t can be up to -32768, which is 6 characters, not 4.  int64_t is even larger.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

1. You write the full buffer, even the parts that are after the null-terminator. This part could be *uninitialized* and have *indeterminate* values.
2. Even if you fill the buffer completely, you write the null-terminator, which shouldn't be written to a text file.

To solve both these issues, use `strlen` instead to get the actual length of the string:

```
write(fd_csv_data, line, strlen(line));
```

---

On another couple of notes:

- Use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf`, to avoid possible buffer overruns
- The size-prefix `l` might be wrong for 64-bit types, use [the standard format macro constants](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer#Format_macro_constants), like `PRId64` for `int64_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Your buffer could overflow, so you'll have to calculate the maximum size of the generated string or just use a buffer big enough.

To write to the file, you can use the return value of `sprintf()`:

```
static char line[256];

int n = sprintf(line, "%d,%d,%d,%ld,%lu\n", ...);

write(fd_csv_data, line, n);
```

As an alternative the safer `snprintf()` could be used.

With some extra checks:

```
#define LINESIZE 256

static char line[LINESIZE];

int n = sprintf(line, "%d,%d,%d,%ld,%lu\n", ...);

if (n > 0 && n < LINESIZE) {

    write(fd_csv_data, line, n);    
}
// else..
```